# Как подключить модуль к проекту?

Tags: delphi

Добрый день, есть проект, главное его окно это PageControl.
Идея такова: сделать несколько программ в одной.

Вопрос: как реализовать так что бы каждая вкладка была отдельным модулем .pas?
Что бы была возможность работы с визуальными кнопками из самого модуля.

Подскажите добрые люди =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Delphi существует такая штука, как TFrame, это почти форма, но самостоятельно, существовать не может. Вы раскидываете там компоненты, код и все такое. 
Для того чтобы фрейм где-то отображался, там создают объект TFrames а этому TFrames указывают TFrame, который нужно отобразить.

В общем изучайте TFrame, и TFrames.